# how to import a module from a different directory in python?

Tags: python, import, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Importing Python modules from different working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046628/importing-python-modules-from-different-working-directory)

I want to import a file that is on the following directory:

```
 E:\edX\cs6.00x\week6\ProblemSet6
```

I was trying:

```
import 'E:\edX\cs6.00x\week6\ProblemSet6\ps6'
```

where ps6.py is the file i wanted imported in the IDLE, but it complains about a sintax error in the last ', how can I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can

```
import sys
sys.path.append("E:\edX\cs6.00x\week6\ProblemSet6")
```

and then simply

```
import ps6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
sys.path.append("E:\edX\cs6.00x\week6\ProblemSet6\ps6")

import file_in_ps6.py
```

Comment: hmm... ps6 is the file I want to open, not a folder

Answer (score 0):

```
import imp
foo = imp.load_source('ps6', 'E:\edX\cs6.00x\week6\ProblemSet6\ps6.py')
foo.BlaBla()
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be to put a mth suffixed file in your sys.prefix directory.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.prefix
'F:\\F-ProgramFiles\\Python-3.2.3'
>>>
```

So in my case the directory is '**F:\F-ProgramFiles\Python-3.2.3**'. I can create a file named forexample
**'mymodules.mth'** in this directory (**with the suffix .mth**) which contains at least two lines with the following syntax:

```
<module1 name without module filename suffix>
<absolute file path to your module1 file>
<module2 name without module filename suffix>
<absolute file path to your module2 file>
<module3 name without module filename suffix>
<absolute file path to your module3 file>
        .
        .
        .
```

After that if you restart a new python session, normally you should have the visibility to your module and
being able to import your desired module(s).

Regards,

Dariyoosh