# Include Python library at path?

Tags: python

Is there a way to import a Python library at a certain path? For example,

```
import os, sys, etc
import "/path/to/lib.py"
```

I'd like to include a library with a python file, and other than making them install the library, this is the best way I can think of.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046628/importing-python-modules-from-different-working-directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
sys.path.append('/path/to')
import lib
```

---

But, to be honest, you shouldn't.
It's pretty easy to install a library, especially using tools such as [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) and [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/).