# Python 3.6 import methods from different subdirectories

Tags: python, import, python-import

I know there are a lot of readings for this topic available, but I can't figure out how to get it work for my specific case.

I have a project structure like this

```
root
    folder1
          __init__.py
          file1.py
          file2.py
    folder2
          __init__.py
          file3.py
          file4.py
          folder3
                 __init__.py
                 file5.py
```

In `file3.py` I have a function `getNumbers()` which i want to import in `file2.py` like this:

`from folder2.file3 import getNumbers()`

The `__init__.py` files are all empty.

I do get Error if I run `file2.py` from `folder1`-directory

`No module named 'folder2'`

How can i get the import from different subdirectories work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing Python modules from different working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046628/importing-python-modules-from-different-working-directory)

Comment: If it is a duplicate, PLEEEEASE for the love of god don't do the path appending thing, build it with imports in a nice pythonic way, people using your code will, at least, not hate you for that.

Comment: `from folder2.file3 import getNumbers()` is invalid syntax: you should use `from folder2.file3 import getNumbers`. By the way, if you run your program from the `root` folder then the import in `file2.py` works fine: I know this is not what you asked, but you might want to consider structuring your program that way if you can (it makes your program more modular/better encapsulated).

Comment: Maybe it is a duplicate but i cannot get it work from your suggested answers. Can someone please provide a solution based on my given project structure? Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python) I highly recommend, checking this out- as this problem has more to do about how you setup yor project then what import your use or what `sys.path` hack you use to fix a bad project structure.

Comment: I cannot get it work.

Answer (score 0):

maybe use this

```
# some_file.py 
import sys 
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/application/app/folder')
```

you may also use `path.append(...)`, for full answer see this link: 
[Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)