# Dealing with subfolders when usin crontab

Tags: python, cron

I'm having some troubles trying to schedule the execution of one project.

The structure is:

```
main folder
 |- lib
 |   |- file1.py
 |   |- file2.py
 |
 |- data
 |   |- file.csv
 |
 |- temp
 |   |- file.json
 |
 |-main.py
```

The contrab line is:

```
*/5 * * * * python3 /home/myName/main_folder/main.py
```

I've been trying this command line with simple python scripts without dependences and works fine. The problem is that in this case the `main.py` import classes and functions inside `lib` and I think it can deal with it.

On my `main.py` I'm importing like this `from lib import file1, file2`. Exists another way maybe using `os` that the program knows the absolute path?

Comment: quickfix: */5 * * * * cd /home/myName/main_folder/; python3 main.py

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046628/importing-python-modules-from-different-working-directory

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add an empty file named: `__init__.py` in **lib** directory.

Comment: yeah. sometimes, without `__init__.py` python fails to recognize the folder as module

Comment: Just in lib or in main folder is a good idea?